# git staged file twice, can you recover the old version?

Tags: git, stage

if i make changes to a file.txt

then `git add file.txt`

then i make more changed to file.txt

then i do `git add file.txt` again

i realize i made a mistake on my second changes/edit to the file. can you go back to the version of the file that i originally staged?

Comment: In this case, a good editor or IDE is your best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in theory the objects are still in `.git/objects` until the next time `git gc` is run (which happens automatically after certain other actions).

Unfortunately figuring out which object could be tricky. If the file was edited and added recently then the time stamp will help.

```
ls -lrt .git/objects/*/* | tail
-r--r--r-- 1 ams users     6976 Apr  6 19:53 .git/objects/0c/3546bd9101264cd6a9fb1fb54cea04c6e0a4b8
```

If you see a file with a likely timestamp then you can retrieve the contents like this:

```
git show 0c3546bd9101264cd6a9fb1fb54cea04c6e0a4b8
```

Comment: This is correct: `git add` enters the file's contents into the repository as a (usually new) blob object, so you simply (hah) need to find the blob.  The `ls`-by-time method is one way, another is to use `git fsck --lost-found` which drops unreferenced blobs into a directory, `.git/lost-found/other` (you can then just grep through the blobs for whatever you are looking for).

Answer (score 1):

As J. Titus said in a comment:

> You never committed to produce a reference, so no.